# Cannot modify the return value of 'Transform.position' because its not a variable

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vector, position

```
for (int i = 0; i < PathLength; i++)
{
    GameObject tile = (GameObject)Instantiate(GroundTile, transform);


    tile.transform.position.x += 1;


}
```

I am trying to add 1 to the x axis of the tile, so if i add 1 again later it will become 2, however it does not work and I get this error:

Cannot modify the return value of 'Transform.position' because it is not a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign the complete vector3 to the transform.position. Try:

```
for (int i = 0; i < PathLength; i++)
{
    GameObject tile = (GameObject)Instantiate(GroundTile, transform);


    tile.transform.position = new Vector3(tile.transform.position.x + 1, tile.transform.position.y, tile.transform.position.z);


}
```

Comment: A bit easier to read in this case would probably be `tile.transform.position += Vector3.right;`