# How to take z value on a position to move a camera? (cannot modify the return value of 'Transform.position'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an object that moves forward backward left and right and i want the camera to move up and down not left and right i tried using the z value but i have an error (im not the best at coding)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/riVoA.png
if you have a answer please help

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
public class followplayer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform playerchar;
    public Vector3 cameraOffset;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        cameraOffset = transform.position - playerchar.transform.position;
    }


    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Vector3 newPosition = playerchar.transform.position + cameraOffset;
        transform.position.z = newPosition.z;
    }
}
```

Comment: [Please include error messages as text instead of images.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot modify the return value of 'Transform.position' because its not a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64942016/1092820)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change transform.position this way. That's the correct way to do so:

```
transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y, newPosition.z);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the Quickway:

```cs
var tPos = transform.position;
tPos.z = newPosition.z;
transform.position = tPos;
```